# Spreadsheetgear - How to set focus on first worksheet

Tags: excel, spreadsheetgear

I am working with [spreadsheetgear](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) to create excel sheet. I am able to add multiple worksheets. After I add more than 1 worksheet, the focus always remains on last worksheet. How can I set focus on first worksheet after adding multiple sheets.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use ISheet.[Select](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.ISheet~Select.html)() to make a sheet the active sheet.  Example:

```
using SpreadsheetGear;
...

IWorkbook workbook = Factory.GetWorkbook();
workbook.Worksheets.Add();
workbook.Worksheets.Add();
workbook.Worksheets.Add();
workbook.Worksheets[0].Select();  // Selects the first sheet in the workbook.
```